# Thunderbird 8 changed default skin/theme - any way to change it back?

Tags: 11.04, thunderbird, themes

I just updated to Thunderbird 8 (I use Mozilla's version, not Ubuntu's) on Ubuntu 11.04; and it seems it has changed its default skin/theme. Not sure how it looks under other OS', but under my Ubuntu, Thunderbird 7 looks like this:

[image: tb7.png]

... while Thunderbird 8 looks like this:

[image: tb8.png]

Now, I'm pretty sure some folks may appreciate the design change - but for me, I got so used to the old one, now everytime I start TB8 my first thought is "*what went wrong, why are the menubars extended, is it a buggy addon?*", and I start looking for ways to shorten them.

So, is there a way to get back to the old design (which wouldn't require rebuilding TB from source)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks too good to be a bug, it looks like it just got better integration. anyway, just uninstall mozillas version, and reinstall whats in the ubuntu repos.

if you installed via a mozilla beta ppa, just purge the ppa and it should downgrade to TB7.

hope this helps you out

(EDIT) this can help you with purging/managing ppas, its called Y PPA Manager

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/y-ppa-manager-0084-released-finally.html

Comment: Thanks for that, @Jayo - I believe I noted it is not an actual bug; its just that I don't like that design, having been too used to the old one - and "bug" is just my initial reaction whenever I start the new version. Btw, I just run Mozilla's version directly from its folder, haven't used a PPA for Firefox - and I would prefer not to downgrade just because of the toolbar design. Thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I now know what to do to fix my theme problem. Don't use Ubuntu version of Thunderbird.

For you; you could try installing gnome-tweak-tool and select a different GTK+ theme, but doubt you will like this as it is for all applications.

Installing a different theme may change it, but these (gnome, adwati) are now buggy with 8.0.